# Is oauth access_token independent of technology i.e. java and .net?

Tags: java, .net, oauth, oauth-2.0

The question basically arises from the below requirement.

**Requirement:-** Oauth token generated in Java for a service and its client is written in written in .Net. Exactly the samething happens vice versa for another set of services.

**Question:-** Oauth Key generation is different in Java and .Net and the way of consuming also. So, is it possible that Oauth access_token generated in Java will be accessed by .Net client and vice versa.

**My understanding:-**

1. Oauth is application specific.
2. Oauth requires any identity server like Active Directory, LDAP etc.
3. Oauth generation of key as Java client requires Base64 etc if consuming token sent by .Net server side.
4. Oauth access_token generated from Java Service (server side) require purely calling service multiple times [1st to fetch access_token on the basis of user credentials and 2nd to call required services for usage].

Comment: Its Oauth, typo at question level, sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question:- Oauth Key generation is different in Java and .Net and the way of consuming also. So, is it possible that Oauth access_token generated in Java will be accessed by .Net client and vice versa.

Yes.  Oauth does not care what languages are used on the client and server side.

> Oauth is application specific.

Incorrect.

> Oauth requires any identity server like Active Directory, LDAP etc.

Incorrect.  The identity information could be represented other ways; e.g. an "/etc/passwd" file.  Oauth (the protocol) doesn't care.

> Oauth generation of key as Java client requires Base64 etc if consuming token sent by .Net server side.

I don't think so.  The client side should have no need to unpick the token.

> Oauth access_token generated from Java Service (server side) require purely calling service multiple times [1st to fetch access_token on the basis of user credentials and 2nd to call required services for usage].

Yes, probably.  It is possible that you *only* want to authenticate the user, but that is pretty unlikely.

Comment: Thnx Stephen, I will try to proceed ahead with the strategy. Appreciate immediate reply.

Answer (score 0):

It's an open standard and isn't linked to any particular programming language or environment.

You might as well ask if Java and .NET can use HTTP to communicate with one another.